readline on wsl cpp stops input from showing after stopping run via vscode interface
My setup includes WSL with Ubuntu, and I'm using Visual Studio Code as my work environment and coding in cpp 17. I've encountered the following issue: whenever I stop the program from running via the stop button in the VS Code interface, the text I input doesn't show up until I press Enter.
This issue doesn't occur when I run ./main via the WSL terminal as there's no way to close the terminal without... well, closing the terminal. I was wondering why this happens.
Here is a minimal reproduction of the issue:
'
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    
  while(true)
    std::string input = readline("shell> "); // run this and close via interface to reproduce

    return 0;
}

Also, using getline isnt an option as in my actual project I want the possibility of going up and down in command history (or at least I dont know how to do so with getline)
I tried a few variations of sig handlers but non resulted in a change
Any insights would be appreciated!
edit: just to clarify, this doesnt really matter to functionality in the end as ill run the program via the wsl terminal anyway but im genuinely curious as to why this happens!
